# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'DescriptionList' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Candidate'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error now but some time ago the app was working fine I only added data to the Model, but it's not used in CandidateHistory.
I really don't understand why it's giving me this error because I didn't change anything on the History controller only added Data to the Candidate Model that is used by other controller...

Here is my ApplicationContext:

```
using HCCBPOHR.Core.Contracts.Data;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;


namespace HCCBPOHR.Data.Context
 {


    public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected IConfiguration _Configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration 
    {

        get
        {
            if (_Configuration == null)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

                _Configuration = builder.Build();
            }

            return _Configuration;
        }
        set
        {
            _Configuration = value;
        }
    }
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
        ConfigAsset(modelBuilder);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void ConfigAsset(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public static IEnumerable<object> ApplicationUser { get; internal set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profile { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ads> Ads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Area { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CandidateAnalytics> CandidateAnalytics { get; set; }


}

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult CandidateHistory(int Id)
    {

        using (var applicationcontext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var candidate = applicationcontext.Candidates.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(Id)).SingleOrDefault();
            //var candidate = applicationcontext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id); //Recieving all the data from the Candidate With the ID = Id
            if (candidate == null) //if Candidate isn't found return a error page
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return View(candidate);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateHistory")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CandidateHistoryPost([Bind("Description, State, DateOfDescription, Saving, Interviewer, Feedback, FeedbackDate, Behavior,InterViewDate")]Candidate candidate, int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
                {
                    //var candidates = applicationContext.Candidates.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(Id)).SingleOrDefault();
                    var candidates = applicationContext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id);    //Getting all the DATA from the Candidate with the Id passed in the Get Method
                    candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidates);
                    applicationContext.Candidates.Add(candidates);
                    applicationContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CandidateHistory");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " + "Try again, and if the problem persists " + "see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And also Here is my View:

```
@model HCCBPOHR.Data.Candidate

@{
ViewData["State"] = "CandidateHistory";
 }
<h2>Canidate - @Model.Name</h2>
<label>History</label>
 <hr />
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> History Of @Model.Name
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    @foreach (var Description in Model.DescriptionList)
    {
        @if (Description.Saving == true)
        {
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li class="timeline">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">@Description.State</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Description.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>Description:</b> @Description.Description</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>Interviewer:</b> @Description.Interviewer</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>Feedback:</b> @Description.Feedback</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>FeedbackDate:</b> @Description.FeedbackDate</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p> <b>Bad behavior:</b> @Description.Behavior</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p> <b>Applied For:</b> @Description.SelectedAd</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        @if (Description.Saving == false)
        {
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">@Description.State</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Description.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>Description:</b> @Description.Description</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>Interviewer:</b> @Description.Interviewer</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>Feedback:</b> @Description.Feedback</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p><b>FeedbackDate:</b> @Description.FeedbackDate</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p> <b>Bad behavior:</b> @Description.Behavior</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p> <b>Applied For:</b> @Description.SelectedAd</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
    }
   </div>
 </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@Model.Saving"> Add History Description</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form asp-action="CandidateHistory">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Estado</label>
                    <select asp-for="State" class="form-control">
                        <option value="FirstIntrerview">First Interview </option>
                        <option value="SecoundInterview">Secound Interview</option>
                        <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="InterViewDate" class="control-label">Interview Date:</label>
                    <input asp-for="InterViewDate" class="form-control" value="" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="InterViewDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label">Description</label>
                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" value="" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Side of History</label>
                    <select asp-for="Saving" class="form-control">
                        <option value="false">Candidate </option>
                        <option value="true">Hitachi</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Interviewer</label>
                    <select asp-for="Interviewer" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Mananger">Mananger </option>
                        <option value="Diretora">Diretora</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>FeedBack</label>
                    <select asp-for="Feedback" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Yes">Yes </option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="FeedbackDate" class="control-label">Feedback Date:</label>
                    <input asp-for="FeedbackDate" class="form-control" value="" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FeedbackDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Bad Behavior?</label>
                    <select asp-for="Behavior" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Yes">Yes </option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group">Date of the HistoryPost</label>
                    <input asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateOfDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my Candidate Model:

```
 public class Candidate : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ProfileText { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
    public string CVNAME { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> ProfileList { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean Saving { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> DescriptionList { get; set; }
    public DateTime FeedbackDate { get; set; }
    public string Feedback { get; set; }
    public String Interviewer { get; set; }
    public DateTime InterViewDate { get; set; }
    public string Behavior { get; set; }
    public List<Ads> AllAds { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAd { get; set; }
    public int Vacancies { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> VacanciesFilled { get; set; }
    public int GivenUp { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Candidate()
    {
        DescriptionList = new List<Candidate>();
        //AllAds = new List<Ads>();
        //VacanciesFilled = new List<Candidate>();
    }


}
```

**UPDATE** I'm getting this error now:

> Message = "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Candidates' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: Please bring code defining your database context and models.

Comment: @KrzysztofUkl I will edit my question!

Comment: Wait, *what?* You are adding the candidate **itself** to its `DescriptionList` (which happens to be a list of... candidates?)? (Not to mention the `VacanciesFilled` which also is a list of *candidates*??)

Comment: @Rafalon yes i tought It was better to do so ( and easier) is there a better way to save the description into a list so I can show it later?

Comment: @DorinMunteanu Is this database-first, code-first or model-first? Because it seems to me there's a serious misconception here

Comment: @Rafalon sorry didn't understood that, im pretty new to this, can you explain better?

Comment: @Rafalon please help me

Comment: @DorinMunteanu sorry I'm not here 24/7. I would have expected `DescriptionList` to be a `List<Description>` for example. It feels very strange that it is a `List<Candidate>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't mark your list of descriptions as `virtual`. Making property virtual makes it navigation property. Otherwise, it is only scalar property.

Note - if you are using database-first approach, check whether you created relationship between Candidate and description list.

EDIT:

As I can see, you didn't specify even foreign key for your relationships. Then, using EF Core Fluent API define relationships inside `OnModelCreating()` method. Maybe this will help you.
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method

Secondly, error of updated question indicates, that you are trying to insert entity with entity into database context. In case, when this feature is turned off in your database, you can turn it off or alternatively creating entities with autogenerated identity, which you can achieve using attribute or ModelBuilder.

The third thing:

```
candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidates);
applicationContext.Candidates.Add(candidates);
```

This is bad - you have to decide, whether you want add entities only into DbContext, setting relations manually, or add to DescriptionList, saving context then.

Comment: I have ask you about definition of DbContext, can u provide it?

Comment: Aftear reading it I did not found it helpfull for my question/problem